# Manipulating dataframe with date time variable in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a data frame like

```
  ID       DATE         TS_EVENT              X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 8:31:09 PM     25   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 8:31:09 PM      0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:22:55 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-03-27 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM   100 354 25
```

Now I want to return a dataframe which will have the four columns ID,DATE,X,Y and Z. But the col "ID" will contain the unique ID, DATE will contain the latest date for that ID and the rest of the cols will have the values corresponding to the latest time stamp (TS_EVENT) for that particular ID.

E.g., in this case for ID0026A the dataframe should look like

```
   ID       DATE       X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-01-03    0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-03-27  100 354 25
```

My dataframe contains 1.2million records and 6000 unique IDs

Note: str of ID is character, str of DATE is date, str of TS_EVENT is character and the rest numeric

So, first I want to convert TS_EVENT into a date-time object and then create the required dataframe.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: @darkage the presented solution didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with ddply

```
d$DATE <- ymd(d$DATE)
d$TS_EVENT <- ymd_hms(d$TS_EVENT)

plyr::ddply(d, .(ID, DATE), summarise, ts = max(TS_EVENT), date = max(DATE),
            x = tail(X,1), y = tail(Y, 1), z = tail(Z, 1))

       ID       DATE                  ts       date   x   y  z
1 ID0026A 2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:36:05 2013-01-03   0   0  0
2 ID0026A 2013-03-27 2013-01-03 11:36:05 2013-03-27 100 354 25
```

this work with dplyr as well

```
d %.%
  dplyr:::group_by(DATE, ID) %.% 
  dplyr:::summarise(ts = max(TS_EVENT), date = max(DATE),
            x = tail(X,1), y= tail(Y, 1), z=tail(Z, 1))


        DATE      ID                  ts       date   x   y  z
1 2013-01-03 ID0026A 2013-01-03 11:36:05 2013-01-03   0   0  0
2 2013-03-27 ID0026A 2013-01-03 11:36:05 2013-03-27 100 354 25
```

Thanks @Arun!!

**EDIT**
I'd like to see this with a `data.table`approach. I'm not being able to do it.

Comment: @Arun it does but do not work anyway. Would you recommend something?

Comment: What do you mean, it's not passing the two variables to `group_by`?

Comment: @Arun, dplyr::group_by is not summarizing considering the levels of ID and DATE as ddply do. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Arun I did it above, in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Did it with commit 1482 from github. Works fine. Since you assume it's already sorted.. it's just: `d %.% group_by(ID, DATE) %.% summarise(x=tail(X,1), y=tail(Y,1), z=tail(Z,1))`. The grouping columns will be added automatically. These are the only other cols that are required.

Comment: I suspect it's because you've loaded `plyr` before `dplyr`. Try it with `dplyr:::summarise(.)`..?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, see my `data.table` solution which I basically took from @Arun's endless edits to my previous posts :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice. Thank you very much! I've to read about it to understand the data.table grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Per @PauloCardoso request, here's the `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
idx <- setDT(df)[, .I[TS_EVENT == max(TS_EVENT)], by = c("ID", "DATE")]$V1
unique(df[idx, -3, with = F], by = c("ID", "DATE"))
## ID       DATE   X   Y  Z
## 1: ID0026A 2013-01-03   0   0  0
## 2: ID0026A 2013-03-27 100 354 25
```

Comment: Arenberg Two questions for you
1. How can I convert a date variable from "1/3/2013" to "2013-01-03" ?
2. If the original time stamp is "1/3/2013 8:13:48 PM" how will I convert it to "2013-01-03 20:13:48"
Note: the original date format is %m/%d/%Y. I actually want it in POSIXct format

Comment: @darkage, for your first question: `as.Date("1/3/2013", format = "%d/%m/%Y")`. For your second question, I'm not sure how to deal with the "PM" part. but a 24h system this should work `as.POSIXct("1/3/2013 20:13:48", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: it works fine with %d/%m/%Y date format, but my format is %m/%d/%Y. It doesn't work with my format.

Comment: So change it in the `format`, i.e, `as.Date("3/1/2013", format = "%m/%d/%Y")` and `as.POSIXct("3/1/2013 20:13:48", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (t is your data frame):

```
 t <- t[ !duplicated(t[c("ID","DATE")], fromLast=TRUE), ][c("ID","DATE","X","Y","Z")]
```

Function duplicated will combine ID and DATE into a unique key, and get the last entry (i.e. latest DATE for that ID). Then add the fields you want to your data frame. Hope this helps.

Outputs:

```
ID       DATE   X   Y  Z
ID0026A 2013-01-03   0   0  0
ID0026A 2013-03-27 100 354 25
```